# Нет реализации типа std::array в заголовочном файле

Tags: c++, массивы, qtcreator, стандарт

Столкнулся с проблем использования типа array в QtCreator 2.5.2, такой заголовок существует но при его использовании (объявления в коде) выдает ошибку компиляции. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

----обновил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

----обновил

вот такой у меня вывод о ошибках

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Следует показать сообщение об ошибке, выдаваемое компилятором.

Comment: @perfect, Вам самому-то нравится, что Вы не видите нормальные сообщения? Может стоит сменить среду?

Comment: @avp я ввел для себя правило - если есть бесплатный продукт то нужно использовать вместо платного. Пиратить я не люблю поскольку это не уважение к программистам. Хорошая среда больших денег стоит под виндой, а у меня нет таких средств.

Comment: Просто переходите на Linux (и забудьте о M$)

Comment: всему свое время. у меня до опенсурсного уровня не хватает знаний английского языка, чем я сейчас и занимаюсь. год просидел на убунте и все бы хорошо но без чтения манов далеко не уедешь. пока что программирование для меня это вселишь развивающая игра.

Comment: @perfect https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx

Comment: @PashaPash а поддержка Qt в этой среде есть? и встанет ли она на XP

Comment: @perfect [скорее всего - да](http://www.oragon.net/qt-vsaddin-vs2013/)

Comment: @PashaPash не подошла по требованиям к ОС. у меня XP

Comment: Совершенно бесплатная Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition спасет начинающего программиста под ХР.

Comment: @outcast у меня компилятор от 2010 экспресс визуал студии. зачем мне старее?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt Creator 3.5.0, msvc2013 - компилируется.

```
#include <array>
std::array<int, 5> b = {1, 2, 3};
```

В pro файле не забыли `CONFIG += c++11`?

UPD: 
В msvc2010 не полностью реализован c++11.

```
std::array<int, 5> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // Компилируется.
std::array<int, 5> a{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // Не компилируется.
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2792103

Comment: у меня сборщик CМake а компилятор сменить не возможно почему то вместо MinGw компилятор mvs 2010

Comment: спасибо помогло

Answer (score 1):

Вам следует указать квалифицированное имя `std::array`, так как этот класс объявлен в стандартном пространстве имен `std`, и ни `using` директивы, ни объявление `using` для этого класса в вашей программе не заданы.

Напишите

```
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 3> a1 { { 1, 2, 3 } };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: несработает я пробовал std пространство подключать, просто поторопился с картинкой, смотрите обновленный ответ.

Comment: @perfect Я не понял, о каком обновленном ответе вы говорите?

Comment: вторю картинку с ошибкой прикрепил к своему ответу с очередной ошибкой после того как меня поправили с пространством std

Comment: @perfect Неужели так трудно показать сообщение об ошибке?! Используйте двойные фигурные скобки.

Comment: среда о ошибках крякозяблами выводит, смысла выкладывать нет

Comment: @perfect В первом своем примере используйте квалифицированное имя. Только и всего. Вы же меняете постоянно пример.

Comment: @perfect Код ошибки приведите.

Comment: обновил ответ смотрите очередную картинку

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, а в чем разница между `array<int, 3> a1 { { 1, 2, 3 } };` и `array<int, 3> a1 { 1, 2, 3 };`? / У меня g++ -std=c++11 воспринимает обе конструкции (тогда зачем лишние символы?)

Comment: @perfect  Вы можете сделать, как я вам написал?! В вашей новой картинке уже используется идентификатор a вместо a1.

Comment: @avp Не все компиляторы воспринимают инициализацию агрегата внутри агрегата без использования вложенных фигурных скобок.

Comment: Так давайте просто не будем использовать плохие компиляторы.

Comment: @avp Это ваше право при условии, что вы найдете хороший компилятор, в чем я очень сомневаюсь, так как любой компилятор имеет баги и не соответствует стандарту.

Comment: Я использую GNU (вместе со всеми его расширениями, несоответствиями "стандарту" и ошибками)

Answer (score 0):

Как заметил @dzhioev, ошибка компиляции возникает скорее всего из-за отсутствия указания пространства имён std.

Второй причиной ошибки может являться отсутствие поддержки C++11 компилятором или отсутствие опции, включающей возможности C++11.

Для GCC:

Узнать версию компилятора: `gcc -v`

Опция для включения C++11: `-std=c++11`

+в данной случае двойные фигурные скобки не нужны.

```
std::array <int, 5> a{ 4, 5, 6 };
```

Comment: +namespace у т.с. не указан

Comment: @dzhioev, да, неизвестная ошибка компиляции скорее всего из-за этого.

Comment: не помогло я пробовал так тоже. смотрите на мой обновленный ответ

Comment: @perfect, в таком случае разумней показать сообщение самой ошибки.

Comment: @perfect, посмотри обновлённый ответ.

Comment: у меня сборщик CMake

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.
Что на счёт сообщения об ошибке?

Comment: среда о ошибках крякозяблами выводит, смысла выкладывать нет

Comment: У тебя же CMake. При чём тут среда?

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28972/discussion-between-perfect-and--).

Comment: как отвечать в чате. у меня нет поля ввода куда можно вставить текст?

Comment: Поле в самом низу.

Comment: нет его там, вижу только ваши сообщения и метки на руском языке у крякозяблами отображаются, а поле ввода поиска вообще вверх за баннер уползло